# A questions about integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $c,m, a$ be positive integer numbers. I have the following integral:
    $$2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(x^2+c)^{\frac{m}{2}}}{x}\mathrm{e}^{-ax}\mathrm{d}x.$$
Although, I tried to solve it by Maple, I could not get the answer

Comment: If $c=0$ you get $2a^{-m}\Gamma(m)$, otherwise the integral does not converge (the integrand is $\sim x^{-1}$ for $x\rightarrow 0$)

Answer (score 1):

As gammatester already commented, there is a major problem around $x=0$. Developed as a Taylor series  around $x=0$, we have $$ \left(x^2+c\right)^{m/2}e^{-a x}=c^{m/2}-a  c^{m/2}x+\frac{1}{2}  c^{\frac{m}{2}-1} \left(a^2
   c+m\right)x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$ which makes 
$$\frac{(x^2+c)^{m/2}}{x}\mathrm{e}^{-ax}=\frac{c^{m/2}}{x}-a c^{m/2}+\frac{1}{2}  c^{\frac{m}{2}-1} \left(a^2
   c+m\right)x+O\left(x^2\right)$$

Any $c\neq 0$ would make the integral not converging for a lower bound equal to $0$.